# Why CoroutineExceptionHandler didn't catch/handle my exception?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

In this code why `handler` only prints the stack-trace for `JobCancellationException` and not `SocketException`? The `foo` function inside `launch` definitely throws `SocketException`, so what happens to it?

```
suspend fun foo() {
  val job = coroutineContext[Job]!!
  val socket = Socket()

  job.invokeOnCompletion(onCancelling = true) {
    if (!socket.isClosed) {
      socket.close()
    }
  }

  // non-routable address -> timeout
  // will throw SocketException after socket.close() is called above
  socket.connect(InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.0", 1234), 2000)
}

fun test() = runBlocking {
  val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
    throwable.printStackTrace()
  }

  val job = launch(DefaultDispatcher + handler) {
    foo()
  }

  delay(100)
  job.cancelAndJoin()
  delay(100)
}
```

Comment: I think runBlocking will not handle CoroutineExceptionHandler

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you why `CoroutineExceptionHandler` didn't catch the exception thrown in `launch`.  But I can tell you 2 things -

1. I verified the behavior you found - you are correct, the exception isn't caught.
2. By experimenting, I learned how to catch the exception in `CoroutineExceptionHandler`.

Here's the code that shows how to catch it:

```
fun f() = runBlocking {
    val eh = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> trace("exception handler: $e") }
    val cs1 = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    val j1 = cs1.launch(eh + CoroutineName("first"))  {
        trace("launched")
        delay(1000)
        throw RuntimeException("error!")
    }
    trace("joining j1")
    j1.join()
    val cs2 = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + eh)
    val j2 = cs2.launch(CoroutineName("second"))  {
        trace("launched")
        delay(1000)
        throw RuntimeException("error!")
    }
    trace("joining j2")
    j2.join()
    trace("after join")
}
f()
```

Console output:

```
[main @coroutine#1]: joining j1
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @first#2]: launched
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @first#2]: exception handler: java.lang.RuntimeException: error!
[main @coroutine#1]: joining j2
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @second#3]: launched
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 @second#3]: exception handler: java.lang.RuntimeException: error!
[main @coroutine#1]: after join
```

The key takeaway is that if you call `launch` on a custom `CoroutineScope`, any `CoroutineExceptionHandler` provided directly to the `CoroutineScope` constructor or to `launch` will be executed when an exception is thrown within the `launch`ed coroutine.

Hope that helps!!

**UPDATE**

I found out why the exception isn't caught.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53588660/369722).