# CoroutineExceptionHandler not executed when provided as launch context

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

When I run this:

```
fun f() = runBlocking {
    val eh = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e -> trace("exception handler: $e") }
    val j1 = launch(eh) {
        trace("launched")
        delay(1000)
        throw RuntimeException("error!")
    }
    trace("joining")
    j1.join()
    trace("after join")
}
f()
```

This is output:

```
[main @coroutine#1]: joining
[main @coroutine#2]: launched
java.lang.RuntimeException: error!
    at ExceptionHandling$f9$1$j1$1.invokeSuspend(ExceptionHandling.kts:164)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.ResumeModeKt.resumeMode(ResumeMode.kt:67)
```

According to the documentation for [CoroutineExceptionHandler](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-exception-handler/index.html), the `eh` handler I provided should be executed.  But it's not.  Why is that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe the answer lies in this section from the [official coroutines docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/exception-handling.md#cancellation-and-exceptions):

> If a coroutine encounters exception other than CancellationException, it cancels its parent with that exception. This behaviour cannot be overridden and is used to provide stable coroutines hierarchies for structured concurrency which do not depend on CoroutineExceptionHandler implementation. The original exception is handled by the parent when all its children terminate.
>
> This also a reason why, in these examples, CoroutineExceptionHandler is always installed to a coroutine that is created in GlobalScope. *It does not make sense to install an exception handler to a coroutine that is launched in the scope of the main runBlocking, since the main coroutine is going to be always cancelled when its child completes with exception despite the installed handler*.

(emphasis mine)

What's described here applies not just to `runBlocking` and `GlobalScope`, but any non-top-level coroutine builder and custom scope.

To illustrate (using kotlinx.coroutines v1.0.0):

```
fun f() = runBlocking {
    val h1 = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
        trace("handler 1 e: $e")
    }
    val h2 = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, e ->
        trace("handler 2 e: $e")
    }
    val cs = CoroutineScope(newSingleThreadContext("t1"))
    trace("launching j1")
    val j1 = cs.launch(h1) {
        delay(1000)
        trace("launching j2")
        val j2 = launch(h2) {
            delay(500)
            trace("throwing exception")
            throw RuntimeException("error!")
        }
        j2.join()
    }
    trace("joining j1")
    j1.join()
    trace("exiting f")
}
f()
```

Output:

```
[main @coroutine#1]: launching j1
[main @coroutine#1]: joining j1
[t1 @coroutine#2]: launching j2
[t1 @coroutine#3]: throwing exception
[t1 @coroutine#2]: handler 1 e: java.lang.RuntimeException: error!
[main @coroutine#1]: exiting f
```

Note that handler `h1` is executed, but `h2` isn't.  This is analogous to the handler on `GlobalScope#launch` executing, but not the handler provided to any `launch` inside `runBlocking`.

TLDR

*Handlers provided to non-root coroutines of a scope will be ignored.  A handler provided to a root coroutine that is created by `launch` will be executed.  Root coroutines created by `async` or `produce` will ignore any handler.*

This behavior makes sense.  If a child coroutine's handler handled an exception, all that coroutine's ancestors up to the root coroutine would have no clear way to continue execution, since they all depend on the success of the child, directly or indirectly.

Similar logic applies to `async`.  If a root coroutine started with `async` could capture exceptions with an installed handler, how would code waiting for a result from the coroutine via `await` know how to proceed with execution after an exception was handled?  As with `launch`, here too, the code cannot proceed unless the coroutine succeeds.

As such, it only makes sense for `launch` root coroutines to have the ability to handle exceptions.

Comment: It gets even weirder: if the root coroutine is an `async` or `produce`, the exception handler will have no effect. The rationale is that you'll get the exception in `await`/`receive`, but a `catch` block there doesn't prevent the entire scope from failing before you reach those lines.

Comment: Would you mind sharing that `trace()` method? It has such a nice info prepended to message.

Comment: @AlexDmitriev This was a long time ago, so I don't have it anymore.  But I think the prepended part is a concatenation of the name of the current thread and that of the current coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

What is your `kotlinx.coroutines` version? Since 0.26.0 standalone `launch` builder is now deprecated and You should be using `GlobalScope.launch` instead.

I tried your sample and after that change it worked.

[Kotlinx.coroutines changelog](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/CHANGES.md#version-0260)

Comment: Thanks @Pawel.  I'm using `v1.0.0`.  In the code sample, I thought I wasn't using the standalone `launch`.  I thought I was using the `launch` that's defined on the `CoroutineScope` that's automatically generated by `runBlocking`.

Comment: @JulianA. if You want to use that scope You'd need to replace your `launch(eh)` with `launch(Job() + eh)` to install the exception handler. I think first case even compiling and not working is just a quirk of `CoroutineExceptionHandler` implementing an internal coroutine interface needed for scope/context stacking (still not sure myself how that works), but itself it does not have an exception handler.

Comment: OP is definitely using the `CoroutoneScope.launch` extension function. The receiver, `this`, is implied. It should have worked. Your suggestion to inject a new Job as the parent isn't good i think, it should be a child of the existing job.

Comment: The reason the syntax works is a general one and non-magical: `CoroutineExceptionHandler` is a `CoroutineContext.Element`, which is a subtype of `CoroutineContext`.