# Why can't runBlocking take in CoroutineExceptionHandler?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When I have

```
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
            println("CoroutineExceptionHandler got $exception")
        }

        GlobalScope.launch(handler) {
            throw IllegalAccessException("Just testing")
        }

        Thread.sleep(300)
    }
```

It works fine printing

```
CoroutineExceptionHandler got java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Just testing

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Even if I replace `GlobalScope` with `MainScope()`, all still work fine.

However, if I use `runBlocking` as below.,

```
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
            println("CoroutineExceptionHandler got $exception")
        }

        runBlocking(handler) {
            throw IllegalAccessException("Just testing")
        }

        Thread.sleep(300)
    }
```

It crashes

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Just testing

    at com.example.coroutinerevise.CoroutineExperiment$test$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutineExperiment.kt:32)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:274)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:84)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.coroutinerevise.CoroutineExperiment.test(CoroutineExperiment.kt:31)
```

Why can't runBlocking have the given `CoroutineExceptionHandler` triggered?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#coroutineexceptionhandler)?

Comment: I have read the documentation. I get the code from the documentation and explore how it works on runBlocking instead of GlobalScope. I also read about this issue https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1746. From it, it looks like the issue Eliazar `runBlocking { ... }` is handled, but not addressing `runBlocking(handler) { ... }`.

I suspect probably a bug when we use `runBlocking(handling)`, that the exception is not handled

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576189/coroutineexceptionhandler-not-executed-when-provided-as-launch-context

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53588660/3286489 doesn't help, as it uses `CoroutineScope(newSingleThreadContext("t1"))` to launch a new coroutine to get the `handler`, and not link to the parent's `runBlocking`

Comment: the way I understand it doesn't matter, because only handler attached to GlobalScope is relevant. try this with your first test `GlobalScope.launch(handler0){withContext(handler1){throw IllegalAccessException("Just testing")}}` where handler0 and handler1 print different messages - handler0 will print because it's attached to GlobalScope

Comment: Using `GlobalScope` will work as mentioned in my question above. But not on `runBlocking`. Is it because this is not supported at all (e.g. I cannot define my own Custom Exception Handler for `runBlocking`), is this is a missed-support from Coroutine, or I didn't implement something right?

Comment: it's not supported as per [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/exception-handling.md#cancellation-and-exceptions)
CoroutineExceptionHandler implementation is not used for child coroutines. [runBlocking](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread interruptibly until its completion. So beacause runBlocking creates a new coroutine it will not work

Answer (score 2):

it's not supported as per
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/exception-handling.md#cancellation-and-exceptions

> If a coroutine encounters an exception other than CancellationException, it cancels its parent with that exception. This behaviour cannot be overridden and is used to provide stable coroutines hierarchies for structured concurrency. CoroutineExceptionHandler implementation is not used for child coroutines.

And runBlocking creates a child coroutine
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html

> Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread interruptibly until its completion.

Something like this will work, but it's kind of ugly

```
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
            println("CoroutineExceptionHandler got $exception")
        }
        try{
            runBlocking {
                throw InterruptedException("Just testing")
            }
        } catch(e:Exception){
            handler.handleException(GlobalScope.coroutineContext,e)
        }
        Thread.sleep(300)
    }
```

Comment: Ya, thanks. This will work, but it is really ugly. There will be in some cases, we want to catch that elegantly, and it is sad that they don't really support it.
I think that only have it for `GlobalScope` top level is not perfect. Sometimes we wanted some lower level coroutine to capture the crash to avoid propagate upward.

Comment: I also noticed that using runBlocking inside `Dispatchers.Default.dispatch(handler){}` has the same behaviour as `GlobalScope.launch(handler)`, as it uses `Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#1,5,main]` rather than `Thread[main @coroutine#1,5,main]`, which is the case for using only runBlocking. Not sure if it helps you, but I found it quite interesting